# Video stream recording from app to server

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I need to come up with a solution that I can use within a HTML5 Mobile App (IOS and Android) to record video messages for job applications onto a server.

I guess the best method is to store and record on the phone and then send to the server with an ID to store - but wondered if anyone had done anything similar and had any advice?

We were considering using Phonegap and I work with a .net developer so he could setup a web-service to store the video server side.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with PhoneGap. Using the [Media Capture API's captureVideo()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo) method you can record video. Then in the success callback of this method you can call [FileTransfer.upload()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload) to send the result to your server.